# How to load Second View from First View with Xamarin/iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I feel like this should be pretty simple to do but I can't seem to find the right way to do it after searching forums.

I just want to load a view from another view. I have a firstViewController and a secondViewController. The app launches with the firstViewController. On that page is a button that calls this code:

```
var controller = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SecondViewController") as UIViewController;
PresentViewController(controller, true, null);
```

This is being called from the firstViewController from this event:

```
button.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                LoadSecondView();

            };
```

I'm just getting into this, so maybe I am just missing something with how it works. The error I get is:

> "Doesn't contain a viewcontroller with identifier SecondViewController"

I have made sure to go into the second view in the storyboard and name it as well.

Anything to guide me in the right direction would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
CallHistoryController callHistory = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("CallHistoryController") as CallHistoryController;
if (callHistory != null)
{
    this.NavigationController.PushViewController(callHistory, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting and referencing the correct Storyboard ID ? see the "Instantiate Storyboards Manually" section:
 http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_storyboards/[image]

```
UIStoryboard board = UIStoryboard.FromName ("PinkViewController", null);
UIViewController vc = (UIViewController)board.InstantiateViewController ("PinkViewController");
```